# Couchbase 3.0 rebalance stuck

Tags: couchbase

I had a 4 node couchbase cluster with 3 buckets each having 1 replica. However when one of my nodes when down a part of my dataset became inaccessible. I thought this might be because of the fact that I have an even number of nodes i.e 4 ( instead of say 3 or 5) and so I failed over 1 node. I then proceeded to rebalance the cluster at which point it got stuck. The only thing I can find in the logs is `Bucket "staging" rebalance does not seem to be swap rebalance`. Any idea how to recover from this ?

In my desperation I also tried changing the replicas of different buckets and then performing a rebalance. Nothing worked. This has happened once before as well, that time I had to dump my whole database out and load it into a brand new cluster because I couldn't even backup my database. This time that path is not an option since the data is critical and uptime is also important.

Comment: Firstly, there is no need to have an odd or an even number of nodes (3 is the recommended minimum, but otherwise no real constraints to the topology).

Have you tried rebalancing the cluster with 3 nodes (with the failed over node removed) before attempting a rebalance to add the failed over node back?

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I did. I removed the 4th node and rebalanced between 3 nodes. This is when it got stuck. Then I did a lot of things in futile attempts to get it unstuck. This included changing replica count and also adding back the failed node. None of them worked. The only combination I thought about but didn't try was to disable all replicas and then rebalance and then add more replicas and rebalance again. I fear possible data loss so I've not tried that yet.

Comment: Sounds like you need to open an issue with Couchbase team. Go to http://www.couchbase.com/issues

Comment: Sounds like you need to log a defect with Caouchbase core team. Go to http://www.couchbase.com/issues and log defect there for ver. 3 ... what you described supposed to work...so they better try to reproduce

Comment: I found a workaround to fix this issue. I created a new cluster consisting of a single node and then I performed XCDR to transfer all my existing cluster data to the new node. After that I restarted my app to use the new cluster and then I removed each node one by one from the old cluster and added it to the new one. I managed to do it with no downtime. I will raise an issue as well regarding this behaviour on couchbase's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase support pointed to a bug where if there are empty vbuckets, rebalancing can hang.  As per them, this is fixed in 2.0 but **this is not !!!!.**
The work around solution is to populate buckets with a minimum of 2048 short time to live (TTL >= (10 minutes per upgrade + (2 x rebalance_time)) x num_nodes) items so all vbuckets have something in them. We then populated all buckets successfully and were able to restart the rebalance process which completed fine.

This works for Couchbase 3.0.

Reference: http://www.pythian.com/blog/couchbase-rebalance-freeze-issue/